# Implications of explicitly casting a value to the type it gets returned as from a function?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint8_t square(uint16_t num, int x) {
    return (uint8_t)(num / x);
}
```

Should you explicitly cast the uint16_t result to uint8_t, or let it be implicitly cast? My concerns are any speed cost, and the compiler complaining, otherwise I think this should work, even if the cast result gets truncated (which it doesn't in my case since num/x is guaranteed to fit inside uint8_t)

Comment: There's not going to be any speed cost if you have any kind of decent optimizing compiler.  The generated code should be 100% identical.  The result is going to be truncated either way.  And as far as the compiler complaining, well, see if yours does or not.

Comment: The result of the division isn't `uint16_t` but `int`, because of type promotions. The cast to `uint8_t` will be done whether or not you explicitly request it. It might silence a compiler warning, there is a possible conflict when the divisor is negative.

Comment: Like @NateEldredge said, it seems the [code generated](https://godbolt.org/z/a9erMMx36) is identical either way (at least for the godbolt platform anyway, and that's nothing to sneeze your nose at...).

Comment: @WeatherVane "The result of the division isn't `uint16_t` but `int`, because of type promotions. " --> maybe.  The quotient will be type `unsigned` when `int/unsigned` are 16-bit,  something common enough in 20204 with embedded machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should you explicitly cast the uint16_t result to uint8_t, or let it
> be implicitly cast?

You cast `int` not `uint16_t` as `uint16_t` is being converted to `int` and then divided by `int`

C standard 6.3.1.1 p.2

> If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is
> converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int.
> These are called the integer promotions.48) All other types are
> unchanged by the integer promotions.

Then you return `uint8_t`. The way `int` is converted to `uint_8` is also defined by the standard:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by
> repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
> can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
> the new type.

> My concerns are any speed cost, and the compiler complaining

The cast does not change anything - the result will the same

> even if the cast result gets truncated (which it doesn't in my case
> since num/x is guaranteed to fit inside `uint8_t`)

The result of your operation can be **negative**.

Answer (score 2):

> Should you explicitly cast the `uint16_t` result to `uint8_t`, or let it be implicitly cast?

Yes, cast.  Picky compiler options may complain about narrowing the result to `uint8_t`, which a cast quiets - that is good.

Yet also consider `num/x` differs when `x < 0` and `int` is 16-bit vs. 32-bit.
IMO, that is a **more important issue** to settle for portable code.  Depending on what OP's wants for that determines the next steps.